# Total read time in Dataflow job has high variance

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I have a Dataflow job that reads log files from my GCS bucket that are split by time and host machine. The structure of the bucket is as follows:

/YYYY/MM/DD/HH/mm/HOST/*.gz

Each job can end up consuming on the order of 10,000+ log files of around 10-100 KB in size.

Normally our job takes approximately 5 minutes to complete. We at times see our jobs spike to 2-3x that amount of time, and find that the majority of the increase is seen in the work items related to reading the data files. How can we reduce this variance on our job execution time? Is there a throughput issue with reading from GCS?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the variance you see in your jobs is due to GCS network latency. While typically the latency to retrieve items from GCS is rather small, it can spike depending on various factors like network conditions and time of day. There is no SLA around latency when it comes to reading from GCS. The throughput from GCS is probably not the factor as the size of the data files you are reading are rather small.

If network conditions are such that your latency increases significantly, this effect will grow proportionally by the number of files you are reading.

One way to alleviate the variance in job time is to try and combine your log files before reading them in such that you have fewer files to read that are larger in size.

Answer (score 0):

I have a different insight on this. Reading a `gzip` file implies it is being unzipped first on the worker machine. The unzip on the `gzip` file is a single core (ideally 1 n1-standard-1 worker) operation because `gzip` as a compression format is not splittable.

In the above scenario, there might be some files which are significantly larger compared to other files and will most likely result into creating stragglers (workers in the dataflow job that lag behind) which will increase the job execution time.

I can think of two solutions to keep the job execution time as minimum as possible -

1. Change to a splittable compression format like `bzip2` so that all the files are massively parallelised and the read operation is completed as fast as possible.
2. Make the `gzip` files as minimum in size as possible so that a large number of workers consume a huge number of files and total execution time is less. For example, having 10 workers read 10 gzip files of 100KB each, have 100 workers read zip files of 10KB each. GCP bills you per minute, so cost should most probably remain the same.